# Locate a search box on navigation bar when using a PHP function?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, web, uinavigationbar

I just found this php function to add a search box on the menu (navigation bar) of my [**website**](http://mamou-mani.com). I am new to php and got the function to work but how could I move it to the very right of my menu bar? Right now the function adds a menu tab and places the box there. Should I use CSS or modify the function itself?

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_box', 10, 2);
function add_search_box($items, $args) {

    ob_start();
    get_search_form();
    $searchform = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $items .= '<li>' . $searchform . '</li>';

return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file:

http://mamou-mani.com/wp-content/themes/modularity/style.css

Change

```
#search { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

to

```
#search { margin: 0; padding: 0; width:395px; }
```

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't work unfortunately. What is the `echo` doing?

Comment: The echo prints out the <div> onto the screen. Maybe you can put the website address so i can check it whats the prob

Comment: Thanks a lot. the link is in the question, [here it is too](http://mamou-mani.com).

Comment: No worries! Most browsers have a debugging tool. Even Microsoft Internet Explorer has one, but it's a bit crappy and slow. I always use the Chrome one, to use it just press CTRL+SHIFT+J or select an element and rihgt click "Inspect element"

Answer (score 0):

You can always position:relative in css and move it